# get rid of youtube logo and autoplay?

Tags: html, video, youtube, shopify

How do I get rid of the youtube logo in the bottom corner? It seems that the usual way is ?modestbranding=1 but that wont work. I've tried making the video autostart too but it seems the more code I add the more I lose. I would like a video without any youtube controls or branding that autoplays. Here is the code I have so far.

```
{% assign slider_enabled = true %}
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    {% for i in (1..6) %}
      {% capture slide %}slide_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
      {% capture slide_link %}slide_{{ i }}_link{% endcapture %}
      {% capture slide_img%}slide_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
      {% capture slide_alt %}slide_{{ i }}_alt{% endcapture %}
      {% if settings[slide] %}

    <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1418/7648/files/slide1.jpg?17428083521508450295">
    <div class="banner_title">
          <h1>A colorful lifestyle</h1>
          <div class="banner-button">
          <a href="https://www.bonmarcheonline.com/collections/best-sellers?sort_by=best-selling{{ settings[slide_link] }}">shop now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    <li><iframe div class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NQFGjQ-gVJw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
          <a href="{{ settings[slide_link] }}" class="slide-link">
            {{ slide_img | asset_img_url: '1920x1024' | img_tag: settings[slide_alt] }}
          </a>
          <div class="banner_title">
          <h1>A colorful lifestyle</h1>
          <div class="banner-button">
          <a href="{{ settings[slide_link] }}">shop now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
    </ul></div>
```

Comment: Why do have `<iframe div class="video" `... iframe and div tag combined?

Comment: It was part of an attempt to resize the video but I've removed it.